# How can read two field of a csv file separately in python?

Tags: python, csv

I want to read two column of a csv file separately, but when I wrote code like below python just show first column and nothing for second, but in the csv file the second column also has lots of rows.

```
import csv
import pprint

f = open("arachnid.csv", 'r')
read = csv.DictReader(f)
for i in range(3):
    read.next()

for i in read:
    pprint.pprint(i["binomialAuthority_label"])

for i in read:
    pprint.pprint(i["rdf-schema#label"])
```

Comment: Why are you reading the two files separately? It is just curiosity.

Comment: no this is part of a exercise and in the question instructor asked it.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this is that when you use DictReader the way you are using it it will create what is called an iterator/generator. So, when you have iterated over it once, you *cannot* iterate over it again the way you are doing it.

If you want to keep your logic as is, you can actually call seek(0) on your file reader object to reset its position as such:

```
f.seek(0)
```

The next time you iterate over your dictreader object, it will give you what you are looking for. So the part of your code of interest would be this:

```
for i in read:
    pprint.pprint(i["binomialAuthority_label"])

# This is where you set your seek(0) before the second loop
f.seek(0)

for i in read:
    pprint.pprint(i['rdf-schema#label'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `DictReader` instance gets exhausted after your first `for i in read:` loop, so when you try to do your second loop, there is nothing to iterate over.

What you want to do, once you've iterated over the CSV the first time, you can seek your file back to the start, and create a new instance of the `DictReader` and start again. You'll want to create a new `DictReader` instance otherwise you'll need to manually skip the header line.

```
f = open(filename)
read = csv.DictReader(f)
for i in read:
    print i

f.seek(0)
read = csv.DictReader(f)
for i in read:
    print i
```